# Use Jquery toggle on repeater items

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am displaying data on my page using repeater and I'd like to use a jquery toggle to show/hide the address fields to make the page more user friendly.

Here is the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterPersonBasicData" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<div id="Maindetails" class="dataContentSection" runat="server">
    <div id="Div1" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span1" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">Name:</span> 
        <span id="Span1444" runat="server"><%# Eval("Name")%></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span3" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">DOB:</span> 
        <span id="Span1443" runat="server"><%# Eval("DOB")%></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Div3" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span5" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">Age:</span> 
        <span id="Span1442" runat="server"><%# Eval("Age")%></span>
    </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="toggleAddressdetails" class="titleText" runat="server">+ Address details</a>
<div id="Addressdetails" class="dataContentSection" runat="server" style="display: none;">
    <div id="Div78" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span144" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">Address Line 1:</span> 
        <span id="Span246" runat="server"><%# Eval("Address1")%></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Div80" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span148" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">>Address Line 2:</span> 
        <span id="Span147" runat="server"><%# Eval("Address2")%></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Div82" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span152" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">>Address Line 3:</span> 
        <span id="Span151" runat="server"><%# Eval("Address3")%></span>
    </div>
    <div id="Div84" visible="true" runat="server">
        <span id="Span156" class="dataFieldText" runat="server">>Address Line 4:</span> 
        <span id="Span155" runat="server"><%# Eval("Address4")%></span>
    </div>
</div>

<br />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Essentially I want to include some javascript like this so that the toggling can be enabled for each repeater item. I tried using .ClientID but this did not work inside the repeater.
Just to prove it would work I have tried including the javascript, and it does work but obviously only for the first five repeater items.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl00_toggleAddressdetails').click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl00_Addressdetails').toggle();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl01_toggleAddressdetails').click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl01_Addressdetails').toggle();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl02_toggleAddressdetails').click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl02_Addressdetails').toggle();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl03_toggleAddressdetails').click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl03_Addressdetails').toggle();
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl04_toggleAddressdetails').click(function () {
            $('#ctl00_cphBody_ctl00_ctl00_RepeaterPersonBasicData_ctl04_Addressdetails').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am of course open to a different approach to achieve the same goal of having the collapsible content inside the repeater.

Comment: why dont you using `classes`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to not use ID's, rather use class names for your selectors.  As an example, here is some HTML based from your code:

```
<div id="repeater">
<!-- item 1 -->
<div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="titleText toggler">+ Address details</a>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
<!-- item 2 -->
<div class="dataContentSection">
    <div>Name</div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="titleText toggler">+ Address details</a>
<div class="dataContentSection" style="display: none;">
    <div>Address Line 1:</div>
    <div>Address Line 2:</div>
    <div>Address Line 3:</div>
</div>
<!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Notice I removed the ID's for simplicity.  I also added the class name 'toggler' to the anchor tags.

Then use this for your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('a.toggler').on('click', function() {
        $('+ div', this).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

When this script is executed, it binds an event handler to all anchor elements with the class name 'toggler'.  The event handler, when executed, simply calls the jQuery toggle() method on the individual element's DIV sibling.

Here is a complete JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P5tZX/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think to use the '+ div' selector to get the next div which is why I didn't think I could uses classes.

Comment: This works really well, I was able to clean up all the long, complex id code from my webform page.  Thanks for posting how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way could be to use classes rather than id selectors. This should work as a starter:

```
$(function () {
  $('a.titleText').on('click', function (ev) {
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
  });
});
```

I would then optimize the event listener to use [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) rather than creating an event for each link.

Comment: Would that only toggle the div for the single repeater item rather than all of them which match the class name?

Comment: No. Reading what the code does sound like this: get all the `a` links with `titleText` class; for each of them, when it is clicked, get the `div` which is immediately following and `toggle()` its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this code is helpful for you. It hides all ".dataContentSection" items, and then just opens ".dataContentSection" element inside the target itemTemplate.

```
$(function () {
  $('a.titleText').on('click', function (ev) {
$(".dataContentSection").each(function(){
$(this.hide();
});
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
  });
});
```